# Can't proceed to install clearcase client in a different windows domain?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I used to install clearcase client on one particular windows domain and was ok. I want to install clearcase in different windows domain but it is not allowing me to map network drive. Do you know if this new domain will allow me to install cc client? One thing to remember: when type "net group  /domain", no cc groups are found ....Is there a way to proceed there?

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because the albd account user isn't allowed to map that new network drive.
See "[Domain user and group accounts](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_domainadm_accounts.htm)".

Plus, installing to a new Windows domain will have [side effects on the existing ClearCase Views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21240535).